# Removing all periods after a letter

Tags: awk, sed

If I have a file like so:

`stuff
 stuff.1
 stuff.2
 stuff.3
 12.5
 45.2
 stugg
 stugg.1
 stugg.2
 5.2
 8
 amber
 amber.1
 amber.2
 amber.3
 amber.4
 7
 21.2
 amst
 amst.1`
 5

and I want to remove duplicates of `stuff` & `stugg` &`amber` &`amst`
where everything ending with `.number` counts as a duplicate how do I do this with awk? or sed?

The output should be

`stuff
 12.5
 45.2
 stugg
 5.2
 8
 amber
 7
 21.2
 amst
 5`

Comment: Is that the entire contents of the file? And are those the only things on the lines?

Comment: That isn't the entire contents of the file,  on some lines there are only numbers like 3.434 or 12.324 while on other lines the file is as explained above.

Comment: And you want to ignore the lines with only numbers completely?

Comment: I would like for the lines which only have numbers to not be altered

Comment: So you want to keep the first unique line of the above lines and leave all *other* lines intact? Is the distinguishing characteristic only alphabetic characters before the `.` versus only numeric characters before the `.`?

Comment: yes I believe that is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -n '/^[[:blank:]]*[[:alpha:]]/ {/\.[[:digit:]]\+$/! p}' file
```

For lines that start with a letter, if the line does not end with a dot and digits, print that line.

---

Found the updated requirements in the comments:

```
awk '$1 !~ /[[:alpha:]]\.[[:digit:]]+$/' file
```

Ah, that will omit something like "notseen.1", even if it's not a duplicate:

```
awk '
  {root = $1; sub(/\.[[:digit:]]+$/, "", root)}
  $1 ~ /[[:alpha:]]\.[[:digit:]]+$/ && seen[root] {next}
  {print; seen[root] = 1}
' file
```

Comment: I apologize, my question was not entirely clear. This does what I initially described but it alters everything else in the file.